# Can't bind custom renderer

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I use AgendaCalendarView library and want to set my custom layout, but i don't know how. When i try without adding custom layout all work fine. I look through many examples, but didn't find anithing. Is it possible to bind this render?

My fragment:

```
public class AdminFragment extends Fragment implements CalendarPickerController {


private AdminViewModel mViewModel;
private AdminFragmentBinding binding;
AdminWorkingTimeControlCardBinding binding2;
private DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
private DateTime selectedDate;

public static AdminFragment newInstance() {
    return new AdminFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.admin_fragment, container, false);
    binding2 = AdminWorkingTimeControlCardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), container,false);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AdminViewModel.class);

    Long userId = getArguments().getLong(WorkersViewModel.workerIdToAdminTag);
    Log.d("work_tag", "Получил юзер Id: " + Long.toString(userId));

    mViewModel.getUsersActivities(userId).observe(AdminFragment.this,
            calendarEvents -> binding.agendaCalendarView.init(calendarEvents,
                    mViewModel.minDate, mViewModel.maxDate, Locale.getDefault(), this));
    binding.agendaCalendarView.addEventRenderer(new ActivityEventRenderer(binding2));
    return binding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AdminViewModel.class);
    binding.setModel(mViewModel);
}

@Override
public void onDaySelected(DayItem dayItem) {
    selectedDate = new DateTime(dayItem.getDate());
    binding.currentDateTextView.setText(selectedDate.toString(dateTimeFormatter));
}

@Override
public void onEventSelected(CalendarEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.format("Selected event: %s", event), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onScrollToDate(Calendar calendar) {
    selectedDate = new DateTime(calendar.getTime());
    binding.currentDateTextView.setText(selectedDate.toString(dateTimeFormatter));
}
```

Renderer for custom layout:

```
public class ActivityEventRenderer extends EventRenderer<ActivityEvent> {
AdminWorkingTimeControlCardBinding binding;

public ActivityEventRenderer(AdminWorkingTimeControlCardBinding binding) {
    this.binding = binding;
}

@Override
public void render(View view, ActivityEvent event) {

  bind(event);

}

void bind(ActivityEvent event) {
    binding.statusTextView.setText(event.getTitle());
    binding.commentTextView.setText(event.getDescription());
    binding.timeButton.setText("12;00");
    binding.executePendingBindings();
}

@Override
public int getEventLayout() {
    return R.layout.admin_working_time_control_card;
}

@Override
public Class<ActivityEvent> getRenderType() {
    return ActivityEvent.class;
}
```

When i launch my code i get:

```
 Process: com.gu.team.workingtimecontrol, PID: 1739
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.tibolte.agendacalendarview.AgendaCalendarView.addEventRenderer(AgendaCalendarView.java:210)
    at com.gu.team.workingtimecontrol.ui.fragments.AdminFragment.onCreateView(AdminFragment.java:60)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2646)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2416)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What kind of binding you are doing, single fragment can not have two views. and two binding.

Comment: In this particular case `admin_fragment` an component with id `agendaCalendarView` So it is creating NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you tell why you are using second binding class. AdminWorkingTimeControlCardBinding

Comment: @Khemraj because in constructor parametr is AdminWorkingTimeControlCardBinding binding

Comment: @Khemraj how i can rewrite class ActivityEventRenderer to make a string "binding.agendaCalendarView.addEventRenderer(new ActivityEventRenderer());" work properly